# Url redirection problems uploading a file in Codeigniter 2.0.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload an image using Codeigniter, following the CI user guide - but I'm getting an error due to the url redirection.

This is my view `upload_form.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

View 2 `upload_success.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
<li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller `upload.php`:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I added the folder "uploads" under the "project_name" folder.

I am using this url for the upload form:

> `localhost/project_name/index.php/upload/`

After submitting I get a "page not found" error and the url becomes:

> `http://localhost/project_name/index.php/upload/localhost/project_name/index.php/upload/do_upload`

Comment: what is your value for $config['base_url'] under config/config.php? because problem is that url should be http:// localhost and not localhost.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.the base url is

Comment: the base url is : $config['base_url'] = 'http:localhost/codeigniter';  codeigniter is the project_name.

Comment: is // part got cut out because it's in comments, or it's missing? $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';

Comment: so // was the answer? I just want to post it, so we can close this thread.

Comment: yes. i missed "//" after "http:"

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments under question:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/set root folder name here/';
```

and use this variable `<?php echo`

Answer (score 0):

*Change the variable name of upload object anything other than* `$config`.
**eg:**

```
$this->**config2** =  array(
                          'upload_path'     => "/root/user_name/public_html/*/files",
                          'upload_url'      => "/root/user_name/public_html/*/files",
                          'allowed_types'   => "pdf|doc",
                          'overwrite'       => TRUE
                      );
$this->load->library('upload', $this->config2);
                if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
                {
                     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                   print_r($error);
                }
```